# Word VBA: Have any character styles been assigned within the selection?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any simple and universal way to find out whether or not any character style has been assigned within the selected text?
Presently I'm using a function, but it is not independent of the MS Word language version:

```
Function AnyCharacterStyleAssigned()
    'elicit the name of the default paragraph font 
    V_AppLang = Application.Language
    If V_AppLang = 1031 Then
        Vst_Default = "Absatz-Standardschriftart"
    ElseIf V_AppLang = 1045 Then
        Vst_Default = "Domy" & ChrW(347) & "lna czcionka akapitu"
    ElseIf V_AppLan = 1033 Then
        Vst_Default = "Default Paragraph Font"
    Else
        MsgBox prompt:="this script doesn't work for this language version of Word", Buttons:=vbOKOnly
        End
    End If

    'search for the default paragraph font within the selection range
    Set R_Range = Selection.Range
    R_Range.Find.ClearFormatting
    R_Range.Find.Style = Vst_Default
    R_Range.Find.Execute findtext:="", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, Format:=True
    AnyCharacterStyleAssigned = IIf(R_Range.Start >= Selection.End, False, True)
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know what to make of your question. For one, I am taken aback by your reference to WinWord. I'm not aware of any connection between VBA and WinWord or if there is VBA in WinWord. I have some knowledge of MS Word and its VBA. In MS Word, there isn't any text to which no character style has been assigned. Therefore a more reasonable question would be which one it is. The default character style is wdStyleNormal which could have any font, and you could ask which one it is. Finally, perhaps you should read up on the "Default Paragraph font" - yet another subject seemingly disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [built-in style constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbuiltinstyle):

```
Function AnyCharacterStyleAssigned()
    'search for the default paragraph font within the selection range
    Set R_Range = Selection.Range
    R_Range.Find.ClearFormatting
    R_Range.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont)
    R_Range.Find.Execute findtext:="", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, Format:=True
    AnyCharacterStyleAssigned = IIf(R_Range.Start >= Selection.End, False, True)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A better test would be the following. The code you have, if the selection doesn't have the style, the selection never changes, so you will always have a True case.

```
Public Sub StyleTest()
    Dim R_Range As Range
    Set R_Range = Selection.Range
    R_Range.Find.ClearFormatting
    R_Range.Find.Style = "Strong"

    Dim AnyCharacterStyleAssigned As Boolean
    AnyCharacterStyleAssigned = False
    If R_Range.Find.Execute(Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, Format:=True) = True Then
        R_Range.Select
        AnyCharacterStyleAssigned = True
    End If
End Sub
```